# KWorld UB435-Q USB ATSC, found but not registering as DVB device

Tags: firmware, dvb

I have a KWorld UB435-Q USB v3 ATSC USB stick, known to work proper on a Win PC.

Now I have a Proxmox host and want to pass it to a docker LXC, to pass it to Tvheadend.

When I plugin the stick I get this output:

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 1b80:e34c Afatech UB435-Q ATSC TV Stick
```

```
[127871.387031] usb 1-2.2: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[127871.487781] usb 1-2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1b80, idProduct=e34c, bcdDevice= 1.00
[127871.487784] usb 1-2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[127871.487785] usb 1-2.2: Product: USB 2875 Device
[127871.487785] usb 1-2.2: SerialNumber: 1
[127871.489016] em28xx 1-2.2:1.0: New device  USB 2875 Device @ 480 Mbps (1b80:e34c, interface 0, class 0)
[127871.489018] em28xx 1-2.2:1.0: DVB interface 0 found: bulk
[127871.547070] em28xx 1-2.2:1.0: chip ID is em2874
[127872.061202] em28xx 1-2.2:1.0: EEPROM ID = 26 00 01 00, EEPROM hash = 0x5d3e97ab
[127872.061207] em28xx 1-2.2:1.0: EEPROM info:
[127872.061208] em28xx 1-2.2:1.0:       microcode start address = 0x0004, boot configuration = 0x01
[127872.083751] em28xx 1-2.2:1.0:       AC97 audio (5 sample rates)
[127872.083754] em28xx 1-2.2:1.0:       500mA max power
[127872.083755] em28xx 1-2.2:1.0:       Table at offset 0x24, strings=0x206a, 0x048a, 0x0000
[127872.143013] em28xx 1-2.2:1.0: Identified as KWorld USB ATSC TV Stick UB435-Q V3 (card=93)
[127872.143018] em28xx 1-2.2:1.0: dvb set to bulk mode.
```

But why doesn't it continue with registring the DVB device like in the docs https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/KWorld_UB435-Q_USB_ATSC_TV_stick:

```
[  175.413555] em2874 #0: Binding DVB extension
[  175.422065] i2c i2c-10: tda18212: NXP TDA18212HN successfully identified
[  175.422071] DVB: registering new adapter (em2874 #0)
[  175.422077] usb 2-1: DVB: registering adapter 1 frontend 0 (LG Electronics LGDT3305 VSB/QAM Frontend)...
[  175.423590] em2874 #0: DVB extension successfully initialized
[  175.423594] em28xx: Registered (Em28xx dvb Extension) extension
```

Is there anything driver I need to load to get it to register as a DVB device?